# A question regarding conditional joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let pdf of $x$, given that $y$=y be $f_{x|y}(x|y)=\frac{x+y}{1+y}e^{-x}, 0<x<\infty,0<y<\infty $. Find $P(x<1|y=2)$. In addition, is it possible to calculate the probability $P(x<1|2<y<3)$ using $f_{x|y}(x|y)$?

For the first part, we just substitute in $y=2$ and integrate with respect to $x$ over the interval ]0,1[.

$P(x<1|y=2)$ =$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x+2}{1+2}e^{-x}  dx$=$\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}(x+2)e^{-x}dx$=...=1-$\frac{4}{3e}$

But the latter question confuses me a little. Isn't $y$ fixed so that it cannot vary between $2<y<3$? Can we calculate $P(x<1|2<y<3)$ using $f_{x|y}(x|y)$?

Comment: The conditional distribution $f_{X\mid Y}$ does not suffice to compute conditional probabilities $P(X\in A\mid Y\in B)$ except when $B$ is a singleton. One would need in addition to know the distribution of $Y$, for example, or the distribution of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Afraid I was a bit trigger happy with the computation there.

Comment: @Did Can you reason why? Is it just because y is fixed by the definition?

Comment: Just look at the definitions... Assuming every density exists and is positive to avoid incongruities, note that $$P(X\in A\mid Y\in B)=\frac{P(X\in A,Y\in B)}{P(Y\in B)}=\frac{\iint_{A\times B}f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)f_Y(y)dxdy}{\int_Bf_Y(y)dy}$$ and that one cannot get rid of $f_Y$.